# Illustrator: How to skew text independently of path?

Tags: adobe-illustrator, text, path, text-wrap

So I have some text wrapped around a circle (with the type on a path tool), and from here I'd like to skew the text so it's slanting a bit to the right. However, when I use the skew tool, it skews the entire path that it's on, but I want to skew the text independent of the path.

I tried skewing the text before wrapping, but pasting into a "type on a path" object removes the skew. Regardless, I'd like the freedom to adjust the skew afterwards if needed.

Is it possible to distort text independently of a text path?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's one method that might work for you.

Type some text, and turn it into outlines, skew it, then turn it into a pattern brush, and apply the brush to the circle.

Some examples:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

I understand what you need and have been there before. I do not believe there is one, simple button that will do this. There are 2 ideas that are "work arounds."

1. Use the italicize version of the font (is this good enough?)
2. After Text on Path in a circle, Convert the Text to Outline (cmd-shift-O), Ungroup the Text, select each letter independently and Skew away (may be tenuous). You may have to rotate all of the letters so the individual letter that is getting skewed is viewing 90 degrees upright.